# How to calculate the variable in foreach with ifnum?

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals, programming

I want to draw some points on a grid with the condition `x-y>1`, and I write the following code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach\x in{1,...,10}{
    \foreach\y in{1,...,10}{
    \ifnum \x-\y>1
        \shade[ball color=red] (\x,\y) circle (0.2cm);
    \else
        \relax
    \fi
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{docume
```

The code above can't be compiled successfully.

Comment: You could also use `ifthen` package.

Comment: You don't need an else branch if you don't do anything. `\if...\fi` would suffice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to evaluate the numeric calculation (`\numexpr`) before testing it as a condition (`\ifnum`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach\x in{1,...,10}{
    \foreach\y in{1,...,10}{
    \ifnum\numexpr\x-\y>1
      \shade[ball color=red] (\x,\y) circle (0.2cm);
    \fi
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The token `>` stops the evaluation of `\numexpr\x-\y`, leaving the evaluated result in the input stream for conditioning against `1`.

---

For more complex evaluations, use `\fpeval` (from [`xfp`](//ctan.org/pkg/xfp)/LaTeX3):

```
%...
\usepackage{xfp}
% ...
\ifnum\fpeval{\x^2+\y^2}<10
% or
\ifnum\fpeval{abs(\x-\y)}<3
%...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :-). Can I make some other math calculation in `ifnum`?  for example the condition is `x^2+y^2<10` or `abs(x-y)<3`.

Comment: @Ice0cean: See the appendage to my answer.

Comment: Also `\foreach\y[evaluate={\z=int(\x-\y);}] in{1,...,10}{\ifnum\z>1\relax...`

Comment: For the floating-point case, you might want to add a `round()` (or similar) function to give an integer answer.